# How to send emails to an email account from an application (just like a "send feedback")

Tags: android

I want to add an activity in my application for sending emails to an account with the ability to attach files. The email id to which the mails will be sent shall remain anonymous to the user just like a send feedback page where you enter the text and a few details and maybe attach a file and it.

Comment: @shkschneider, I don't think this is a duplicate, since the OP wants the receiver to be anonymous, and not the user of the app.

Comment: I want the user to be able to send feedback(text and file, like screenshot) along with his/her email id(optional) and comments or queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that using the default mail clients, installed on the local machine, since they all have a User Interface that displays the receiver of the email.

Using an SMTP server, it is possible, to send an email without UI. But then you have to get the email adress of the current user (if you want to include it). You probably have to login to a SMTP server, so you have to provide your username and password. Or you could create a webservice that sends the email for you.

Why don't you use [Google Forms](http://www.google.com/forms/about/)?

Comment: I don't think google forms has the option to attach files while submitting.